# Unable to clean sendmail/ssmtp output queue

Tags: smtp, sendmail

I have an old message stuck somewhere. The recipient's address is invalid and the system keeps trying to re-send despite mail output queue being supposedly empty. Any ideas where I should look for the stuck message?

```
~$ mailq
mailq: Mail queue is empty
~$ sendmail -bp
sendmail: Mail queue is empty
```

My /var/log/mail reads:

```
Jan  3 17:00:02 my-linux-box sSMTP[15504]: Creating SSL connection to host
Jan  3 17:00:03 my-linux-box sSMTP[15504]: SSL connection using RSA_ARCFOUR_SHA1
Jan  3 17:00:07 my-linux-box sSMTP[15504]: Sent mail for myuser@myuser.com (221 2.0
```

Comment: Bumping up... even though it's been over a month would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: if you have a file `~/dead.letter`, I found this to work `cat ~/dead.letter | sendmail user@domain.tld`.

Comment: @Sebastian: if the mail address is wrong, you will just repeat the error. But in fact the `dead.letter` exists because the mail was not accepted by the first MTA (beeing local or remote) when submited by the mail agent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the message is probably not in the queue, as soon as ssmtp doesn't manage queues at all.

Maybe some applications tries to send a message one in a while, so you could try find that app and remove mail sending logic.
In my case I couldn't remember which app that was so I just uninstalled ssmpt from the system.